# How to create a threaded discussion?

Tags: html, css, sql-server, asp-classic

I am trying to create a threaded discussion and I am having a very hard time coding it.

Below is my MSSQL Server Table Structure:

```
replyID (auto int)
superID
parentID
childID
date
lineage (hex value of path for sorting purposes)
path
body, etc...
```

Here is sample data without the fields that are not important for sorting purposes:

I included the date, lineage, and path for reference.

NOTE: I am sorting on superID desc, lineage asc:

```
rid sid pid cid date                    lineage             path
84  84  0   0   2014-05-13 05:23:05.860 0x                  /
85  84  84  0   2014-05-13 05:23:34.707 0xE00652            /84/0/
86  84  85  1   2014-05-13 05:23:58.383 0xE0067801B580      /84/85/1/
87  84  85  1   2014-05-13 05:24:11.567 0xE0067801B580      /84/85/1/
88  84  86  2   2014-05-13 05:24:24.580 0xE0067801BE0075A0  /84/85/86/2/
76  76  0   0   2014-05-13 04:43:20.483 0x                  /
77  76  76  0   2014-05-13 04:43:34.837 0xDB9480            /76/0/
78  76  77  1   2014-05-13 04:44:13.390 0xDB9DBB58          /76/77/1/
79  76  77  1   2014-05-13 04:45:30.500 0xDB9DBB58          /76/77/1/
80  76  78  2   2014-05-13 04:45:45.303 0xDB9DBBDBD680      /76/77/78/2/
82  76  78  2   2014-05-13 04:56:03.090 0xDB9DBBDBD680      /76/77/78/2/
81  76  80  3   2014-05-13 04:46:36.930 0xDB9DBBDBDE0045E0  /76/77/78/80/3/
83  76  79  2   2014-05-13 04:58:14.163 0xDB9DBBDBF680      /76/77/79/2/
75  75  0   0   2014-05-13 04:43:02.253 0x                  /
```

Using conditional statements, how would you create a tree-view threaded message output based on this structure with classic ASP?

Please advise.

Someone mentioned to show what I've completed so far. The problem is what I have below intentionally does not work because I was troubleshooting it and I just wanted to get a simple layout.

Turning this into a tree structure is the problem.

BTW, I'm using Bootstrap 3 if that is of any help.

```
    set RSDetails= Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

mySQL = "SELECT a.item_replyid,a.item_superid,a.item_parentid,a.item_childid,a.item_replyunique,a.item_topicid,a.item_replydate,a.item_replyuser,a.item_reply,a.item_lineage,a.item_lineage.ToString() AS path,a.item_r_rate,b.id,b.user_unique,b.username,b.auth_image" _
   & " FROM item_replies AS a, item_users AS B " _
   & " WHERE a.item_topicid = '" & pidarticle & "'" _
   & " AND a.item_replyuser = b.ID " _
   & " AND a.item_replyactive = 1 " _
   & " ORDER BY a.item_superid DESC, a.item_lineage ASC;"
    'response.write mySQL&"<hr>"
    RSDetails.CursorLocation = 3 'adUseClient
    RSDetails.Open mySQL, adoCon, 3, 1, 1
    IF Not RSDetails.EOF THEN
        arrDetails=RSDetails.GetRows() 
        errDetails=0
        numRecords=RSDetails.RecordCount
    ELSE 
        errDetails=1
    END IF
    RSDetails.Close

<ul class="media-list">
<%
'response.write "PIisless is " & PIisless & "<hr>"
prevparent = -1
        For iDetails = (PageSize*(PageIndex-1)) to PIisless
        acommentid = arrDetails( 0, iDetails ) 
        acommentsuper = arrDetails( 1, iDetails )
        acommentparent = arrDetails( 2, iDetails )
        acommentchild = arrDetails( 3, iDetails )       
        acommentunique = arrDetails( 4, iDetails )  
        comment_date = arrDetails( 6, iDetails )
        comment_userid = arrDetails( 7, iDetails )
        comment_text = arrDetails( 8, iDetails )
        path = arrDetails( 10, iDetails )       
        item_r_rate = arrDetails( 11, iDetails )
        user_unique = arrDetails( 13, iDetails )
        comment_username = arrDetails( 14, iDetails )
        auth_icon = arrDetails( 15, iDetails )
abuseurl = "Abuse: "&pidarticle&"/"&acommentid&""
abuseurl = Server.URLEncode(abuseurl)
if Len(auth_icon)>0 then
imagesize = "s144"
item_image = "<a class=""pull-left"" href=""http://fakedomain.com/b/"&comment_userid&"/"&FormatTitle(comment_username)&"""><img src="""&resize(auth_icon,imagesize)&""" border=""0"" class=""media-object""/></a>"
else
item_image = ""
end if  
if (acommentsuper <> prevsuper) then
%>
    <li class="media">
<% end if
 if acommentparent <> prevsuperid then %>
   <div class="reply"><div class="ui-group-buttons pull-left">
                <% if showrank=1 then %><a href="javascript:makeRequest('http://fakedomain.com/queryrate.asp?id=<%=acommentunique%>&p1=1&m1=0&r=1&t=0&m=<%=vmember_unique%>&a=<%=user_unique%>');" class="btn btn-success" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></a><% end if %>
                <div><span id="RATING_<%=acommentunique%>" class="rank"><%=item_r_rate%></span></div>
               <% if showrank=1 then %> <a href="javascript:makeRequest('http://fakedomain.com/queryrate.asp?id=<%=acommentunique%>&p1=0&m1=1&r=1&t=0&m=<%=vmember_unique%>&a=<%=user_unique%>');" class="btn btn-danger" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span></a><%end if %></div>
   <%=item_image%>
    <div class="media-body">
    <a name="<%=acommentunique%>"></a>
<% end if %>    
<% if acommentparent = prevsuperid then %>
      <!-- Nested media object -->
<div class="plain media">
<div class="reply"><div class="ui-group-buttons pull-left">
                <% if showrank=1 then %><a href="javascript:makeRequest('http://fakedomain.com/queryrate.asp?id=<%=acommentunique%>&p1=1&m1=0&r=1&t=0&m=<%=vmember_unique%>&a=<%=user_unique%>');" class="btn btn-success" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></a><% end if %>
                <div><span id="RATING_<%=acommentunique%>" class="rank"><%=item_r_rate%></span></div>
               <% if showrank=1 then %> <a href="javascript:makeRequest('http://fakedomain.com/queryrate.asp?id=<%=acommentunique%>&p1=0&m1=1&r=1&t=0&m=<%=vmember_unique%>&a=<%=user_unique%>');" class="btn btn-danger" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span></a><%end if %></div>
<%=item_image%>
    <div class="media-body">
    <a name="<%=acommentunique%>"></a>
   <%end if %>
      <h4 class="media-heading"><% if comment_name<>"" then %><%=comment_name%><% else %><a href="../../b/<%=FormatTitle(comment_username)%>"><%=comment_username %><% end if%> said:</a></h4>
<a name="<%=acommentid%>"></a><%=(comment_text)%>
<div id="reply"><a href="../../newreply.asp?insert=add&recid=<%=acommentunique%>&tid=<%=item_uniqueid%>&gid=<%=group_unique%>&cid=<%=acommentchild%>" class="Butt">Reply</a> | <% if (cuser_unique = comment_userid) or (Session("priv")="1") or (comment_userid = Session("id")) then %><a href="../../newreply.asp?action=edit&recid=<%=acommentunique%>&gid=<%=group_unique%>">Edit</a>  |  <a href="../../newreply.asp?action=edit&recid=<%=acommentunique%>&gid=<%=group_unique%>&redir=<%=redir%>#commentstop">Delete</a> | <% end if %><%=TimeSince(comment_date)%>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../../contact.asp?emailSubject=<%=abuseurl%>" class="report">Report</a> | P: <%=acommentparent%> C: <%=acommentchild%> Path: <%=path%> | acommentparrent: <%=acommentparent%> prevparent: <%=prevcomment%> | super/parent/child <%=acommentsuper%>/<%=acommentparent%>/<%=acommentchild%></div><!--reply-->
<% if acommentparent = prevparent then %>
    </div><!--media-body-->
     </div><!--reply-->  
     </div><!--plain media-->     
<% end if %>
<% if acommentparent <> prevparent then %>     
    </div><!--media-body-->
     </div><!--reply-->    
<% end if
if (acommentsuper <> prevsuper) then %>
</li><!--media-->
<% end if 
prevcomment = acommentparent
prevsuper = acommentsuper
prevparent = acommentparent
prevchild = acommentchild
Next
Set arrDetails = nothing 
%>
</ul><!--medialist-->
```

What the output should look like, based on the data above:

```
Reply A
|_reply 1
  |_reply 2
  |_reply 3
    |_reply 4
Reply B
|_reply 1
  |_reply 2
  |_reply 3
    |_reply 4
    |_reply 5
      |_reply 6
    |_reply 7
Reply C
```

Comment: @JohnConde, what did you edit and why downvote my question to discourage people from helping me?

Comment: I took the languages you put in your title out as they are [not wanted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253028/why-is-removing-tags-from-the-title-suggested-so-often). You probably got downvoted because you made no effort to solve this yourself. And downvotes don't discourage people from answering questions.

Comment: No effort to solve this myself? I have tried for ages to solve this. This is why I'm posting it. Look at that data structure I created. I don't create data structure so I don't have to solve it. This is basic iteration through an array/recordset. I'm been on this for weeks, and actually started it in 2011.

Comment: If you want to show an effort, show the code you've written that doesn't work. That will help us troubleshoot it and this question won't look like you're asking us to do your work for you.